# How to redraw / refresh map on canvas resize?

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

I've created a web page that contains a button to set the map full screen and back to its normal form, the problem map doesn't set to full screen until I resize the output window, how to overcome this,

Any guidance and help is appreciated.

Here is the working example: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gbsandeep/TXbBc/2/)

Comment: see also here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/openlayers-redrawing-map-after-container-resize

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Add `map.updateSize();` to the end of `$("#btn-full-screen").click...`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yWvCN/)

[updateSize documentation](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize)

> This function should be called by any external
> code which dynamically changes the size of the map div (because
> mozilla wont let us catch the “onresize” for an element)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`OpenLayers.Map.updateSize`](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#updateSize) method to redraw your base Layer when you maximize the map.

So, adding a function like:

```
var fullScreen = function () {
    map.baseLayer().redraw();
}
```

you would only need to add an additional option to your map:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0),
    updateSize: fullScreen,
    minResolution: "auto",
    minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
    maxResolution: "auto",
    maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-180, -90, 180, 90),
    projection: Mercator,
    displayProjection: Geographic
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: It doesn't set map to full screen, can you please update the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I had tiles becoming white when zooming using `transitionEffect: 'resize'`. `map.baseLayer().redraw();` fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code whenever you are required to redraw the map like on window resize or on tabs change or full screen or on any other event according to your need.

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
```

this will automatically trigger the `updateSize()` function internally.