# fluid openlayers - responsive design

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to have my openlayers map fit the size of the browser and also resize every time the browser resizes. So I can have responsive design.

My structure of code is like so

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='OpenLayers.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>


var map;
var options = {   
  controls: [],
  maxResolution: "auto",
  projection: "EPSG:900913",
  units: 'm'
}

function init(){
 map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', options);
 //set layers, styles for vectors layers, set and activate click events etc.
}

</script>


<body onload='init();'>

<div id='map_element' style=" width:800px; height:400px ; z-index:1; position: relative;text-align:center;"> </div>
```

According to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/openlayers-redrawing-map-after-container-resize) I tried using

```
//if browser loads 
//this is inside init() because = body.onload > init > resize map
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element', options);
map.updateSize();

//if browser resized
    window.onresize = function()
    {map.updateSize();}
```

but does not work

Also, if I set `style=" width:100%;` in the `map_element` `div` the map disappears from the page.

What is happening? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
style="border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;"
```

Comment: Well, works, but not actually works...Setting `position:absolute` to the map's div makes the div NOT scroll up and down,along with the rest content of the page...Setting `position relative` fixes the scroll but not the responsive issue. Any advise? Thanks

Comment: EDIT Works even without setting `position` for the map's `div`. But there is a precondition. The `div` that contains the map's `div` must have `width` and `height`. In my case, if I set a height, then some elements overflow, since I have a dynamic content. So , fixes the map, "destroys" the container...Think I'm gonna set no height for the container and just use media queries for the map

Answer (score 0):

I try something and it gave me good results, you only have to call in  events resize and turn

Just put the width and height to 100%

[Cannot set map's div height for openlayers map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887506/cannot-set-maps-div-height-for-openlayers-map)