# OpenLayers map interaction issue on margin left

Tags: javascript, openlayers, css

I have created a sidebar that opens and closes. When it opens, it adds margin to the map container ( calling w3_open() ). See pen below.

However the interactions on the map e.g. clicking on the feature (getfeatureinfo) is wrong when there is margin on the left. I click on one feature but another feature is clicked

Probably I need to update map view when there it adds margin?

> Also note that when open and close browser's console for some weird reason the problem is fixed.

https://codepen.io/csandreas1/pen/xoWGyB?editors=1010

```
<script>
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'none';
}
function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: does this help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31409/openlayers-redrawing-map-after-container-resize

Comment: calling `map.updateSize();` actually caused me more issues

Comment: probably, i'll need to add margin to the map itself. Cause i am pushing it to the right 20%.

Comment: This can be solved by removing the margin from the container that the map is in. But still this is not the answer on this question

Comment: i did some quick and dirty testing and i think you have to call `map.updateSize();` and redraw the popup overlay. this way i was able to get the same coordinate after opening/closing the menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `map.updateSize()` is the right solution, but it's not enough. It has to be called at the right time, after side menu animation is finished. The simples solution is to use `setTimeout` call with the proper delay.

Code would then look something like this:

```
function w3_open() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "25%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = 'none';
  setTimeout(function() {map.updateSize();}, 500);
}
function w3_close() {
  document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0%";
  document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "inline-block";
  setTimeout(function() {map.updateSize();}, 500);
}
```